# How to Check References of Annotated Methods

Tags: java, annotations, code-analysis

I'm trying to find a way to check my classes for references of methods with a particular annotation (think "Deprecated").

As far as i see it, analysing *byte code* won't work because it doesn't contain any annotations.
Using *APT* doesn't really help because i need the *references* to the methods, not the annotated methods themselves.

So, what options do i have?

The best i can come up with is compiling a list of the annotated methods followed by a full code analysis, checking every method call against the list.
Is there a way to do that efficiently in an eclipse plug-in or an ant task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analysing bytecode will works!
[ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html)  for an example is handling annotation very well.

Comment: wait... you're right. What made me think annotations don't get compiled to the byte code?

Answer (score 2):

In another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655412/is-there-a-java-parser-for-the-java-language) I asked for a Java parser of the Java language. For my analysis of code I use [this one](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/). Perhaps it's good for you, too.

Comment: Frankly i can't remember what i needed this for. But i believe i built it into our Eclipse plugin and Eclipse will do the parsing for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library, it's simple as:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.package", new MethodAnnotationsScanner());
Set<Method> deprecated = reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(Deprecated.class);
```